# How can I detect if the volume is set to mute?

Tags: android, audio, volume

When I am developing an Android application, how can I detect if volume is set to mute?

How can my application get notified if the volume changes to mute or gets unmuted?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use AudioManager to check volume is mute or not mute.

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch( audio.getRingerMode() ){
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
   break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
   break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
   break;
}
```

and for Volume change there is BroadcastReceiver for that.

```
public class VolumeKeyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Implement Logic
    }
}
```

Register the BroadcastReceiver

```
VolumeKeyReceiver keyReceiver = new VolumeKeyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");
registerReceiver(keyReceiver, intentFilter);
```